# Hibernate transactions in second level cache

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-boot, transactions

Generally, **hibernate transactions** are based on *first level caching sessions*.
How to create a session in Hibernate that accesses a second level cache?

Is it possible?

Comment: you have to activate explicitly second level cache (ehCache).By default first-level cache bind with session.

Comment: how to enable it for a particular transaction only? others should be in default first level.

Comment: you can use query level cache for a particular query.

Comment: Can you provide an example? It will be a great help for me. The resources of internet says different conflicting implementations on that. :(

Answer (score 0):

Only first level cache is managed with hibernate session, but The second level cache is maintained at the SessionFactory level.

https://www.journaldev.com/2980/hibernate-ehcache-hibernate-second-level-cache